# Origins of "большая шишка"

Tags: connotation

Usuallly this saying seems to mean that somebody has significant (esp. political or state service?) career achievements. 
The connotation is not quite clear however.

What is its original source - were/are there other meanings as well?

Comment: The same question on Rus:SE - [Почему шишка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20680/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: The key here is not "career achievements" but the influence he had got by that career. It is about his political power, power of decision-making, power to scree lives of "little men", etc. The connotation can vary from advice to win him as an ally for your case to neutral "if you want to push for that change he is the right avenue" to negative "beware and set back while you are still safe"

Answer (score 4):

Шишка (иноск. ирон.) человѣкъ вліятельный, выскочившій въ люди (**намекъ на замѣтную шишку, выскачившую на лицѣ**).

> Ср. Ого, франтъ, франтъ! — говорилъ Бондыревъ. — Ну, а мы братъ, по деревенскому омужичились... А ты, видно, шишка, въ гору пошелъ!...
>   Н. Крашенинниковъ. Въ уголкѣ. 1.

The source is a phraseological dictionary dated from the 19 century.

Русская мысль и речь. Свое и чужое. Опыт русской фразеологии. Сборник образных слов и иносказаний. Т.Т. 1—2. Ходячие и меткие слова. Сборник русских и иностранных цитат, пословиц, поговорок, пословичных выражений и отдельных слов. СПб., тип. Ак. наук.. М. И. Михельсон. 1896—1912.

Answer (score 4):

В книге Павла Зарубина "Тёмные и светлые стороны русской жизни" (1872-го года издания) есть такая цитата:

> Коренная шишка называется самый передний бурлак из всей артели, которая лямками тянет бичеву.

[В книге](http://www.rusinst.ru/docs/books/I.G.Pryjov-Ocherki_russkogo_byta.pdf) "Очерки русского быта" Ивана Прыжова, русского [этнографа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), читаем:

> «Что вы теперь будете делать? – спросила она у бурлаков. – Ужинать,
>   что ли?» – «Ужинать?! – зарычал шишка – главный мученик, который
>   тянет лямку впереди всех.

Вот другая [цитата](http://turpotveri.ru/kraevedenie/596-vyshnevoloczkaya-vodnaya-sistema.html):

> От кормы судна к берегу тянутся бечевы, в которые впрягают­ся лошади.
>   Барку тащат девять лошадей. Впереди идет коренная - «шишка», а за ней
>   четыре пары, од­на за другой.

В простонародном языке у слова шишка было много значений - от холмика, от выступа на шлеме и до коренника, корневой лошади, тянущей груз. Я не берусь предполагать, что именно это значение (лидер группы) было иронично переосмысленно и превратилось в `важную шишку` или `большую шишку`, но замечу, что, например, с такими словами как "альфа-самец" или даже "передовик производства" такое ироничное переосмысление имело место быть.

Насколько мне известно, "важная шишка" в значении крупный чин закрепилось относительно поздно, в последней четверти 19-го века. Этимология от шишки на лбу тем не менее мне представляется сомнительной - когда говорят о важной/большой шишке никто не подразумевает, что высокое положение в обществе было достигнуто быстро, речь только о самом факте высокого положения.

Скорее просто и в случае шишки на лбу, и в случае важной шишки - это переносное от чего-то выдающегося на общем фоне (и одновременно довольно смешного, нелепого).